# Google Drive API getting an empty ByteArray when downloading/exporting files

Tags: java, google-app-engine, download, google-drive-api

When trying to export files from Drive as PDF stream (from a gdoc), sometimes I get an empty InputStream byte array (it looks like it happens for the large files but I can't confirm!) :

```
InputStream mediaContent = service.files().export(fileId, mimetype).executeMediaAsInputStream();
if(!(mediaContent.available()>0)) {
   throw new IOException("Media content empty, bytes expected");
}
```

No exception is thrown. I can't see any specified limits in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads). Is there any solution to this problem? Is it an known issue?

Drive API : Java client version v3-rev69-1.22.0

***EDIT***

Through the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground usually the request works but fails sometimes as well (by failing I mean it returns the http code 200 but an empty content!).
When using resumable media download, I always get an empty InputStream byte array (chunks of 1MB) :

```
Drive.Files.Export request = service.files().export(fileId, mimetype);
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setChunkSize(Constants.CHUNK_SIZE);
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(false);
InputStream mediaContent = request.executeMediaAsInputStream();
```

But it does not throw any exception (return code 200 as well). Is there a solution?

Comment: Is the file larger than 5MB?

Comment: Hi noogui, thanks for your reply. As it is a Google Docs document, no size is specified in Google Drive. If I download it as a PDF through the Drive UI, I get a file of 382 Ko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone runs into the same problem : I created a ticket to Google Cloud Support and they found that the conversion wasn't completed successfully despite 200 response code. They had also mentioned that the conversion failed on timeout, because the document is very big (conversion couldn't complete in time). So they recommend as a workaround to split document to parts before conversion until they fix the bug on their side.

***EDIT***

Last update from Google support :

Engineers are still investigating this issue, there's no ETA for a resolution and no significant progress was made.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings and the outcome of the support ticket with the community.  Is there a public issue for this that others can follow along to get updates?  If so, can you post a link in your answer?

Comment: Hi Nicholas. As far as I know, there is no public issue for now. I will update this thread in case Google creates one.